# Redux call function and dispatch type in same function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a redux actions for sessiontimeout and logout. When Sessiontimeout called, Internally calling the logout function.

It did not work also `SESSIONTIMEOUT` action type not dispatched.

How I suppose to call logout in Sessiontimeout and dispatch both `SESSIONTIMEOUT` and `LOGOUT`

```
export function sessionTimeOut(){
    return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: ACTIONTYPES.SESSIONTIMEOUT
    })
    }
    logout()
}

export function logout(){
    history.push('/')
    return { 
        type: ACTIONTYPES.LOGOUT 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dispatch `logout()` right after the `SESSIONTIMEOUT` action.

```
  export function sessionTimeOut(){
        return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ACTIONTYPES.SESSIONTIMEOUT
        });
        dispatch(logout());
        } 
    }
```